# How to create from sources deb packages for different architectures

Tags: debian, apt, compiling, packaging, apt-offline

I have to install a software on some devices with debian package, it isn't available for their architectures on apt for debian (but it is available for other distibutions as e.g. ubuntu), and they aren't powerful enough to compile it on themselves.
Considering that sources are available I want to use another machine to create an easily offline installable deb package.
Is there a way (or better some automatic way with something like `apt-build`) to do this properly without messing with all dependencies manually?

Comment: @Quasímodo I know it is buildable for arm because it is already available for arm on other distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pbuilder](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) or [Sbuild](https://wiki.debian.org/sbuild) to build in your more powerful machine.

Comment: Thanks I will check. Some more detail on main differences between one option or another? What is more easy to use?

Comment: This is a common doubt, they are pretty similar, I'm sure there was a question on Askubuntu but I failed to find it. I'd pick the one with better tutorial. Debian and Ubuntu tutorials aren't great in my humble opinion. They are outdated or makes one get lost into details.

Comment: [This `pbuilder` configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_build_for_different_distributions) is very handy for building for different distros and arches (*e.g.* `i386` on `amd64`). `sbuild` supports cross-building so it may be better-suited if you need to build for architectures which can’t run natively on your builder.

Comment: Thanks for the additional resources, @StephenKitt. Do you see advantages to prefer that to a simpler `pbuilder-dist dist arch build x.dsc`? (At least judging by the header, "How to build for different distributions", that should do it IIRC.)

Comment: @Quasímodo I’ve never tried `pbuilder-dist`, it didn’t exist when I set my  multi-distro/multi-arch `pbuilder` up! So I don’t have an informed opinion.